# How to import an xml file with javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

So i've been googling this for a while now and no solution seems to work for me.

Given that the url to the xml file (taken from valve api) is: playerSummariesXml

I tried ajax calls such as:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
       alert(xhttp);
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", playerSummariesXml, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Which returns the link to my website with a /0 appended to the end, 
and

```
  xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
```

which says activexObject not declared

And other things... 
Is there one resolute way to pull an xml file with javascript from a given url and read/display it?

I'm getting really confused considering this is super easy to do with php and don't see why I can't find a similar thing with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below code,

```
var xhttp;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}else {
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
       alert(xhttp);
    }
}

xhttp.open("GET", playerSummaries.xml, true);
xhttp.send();
```

1: you need to check if browser supports `XMLHttpRequest` or `ActiveXObject` Object.
  2: `.open()` and `.send()` should not be written inside `onreadystatechange` function.
  3: check if your referencing your xml file correctly, `playerSummaries.xml` or `playerSummariesXml.`

You can see my below code on GIT hub , which uses plain JS ajax to support for html,css,json ,xml,image responses.
  https://github.com/vijaysani/JavascriptAjaxWithDifferentResponses

let me know if your still facing any issues.

Comment: on the line: xhttp.send(); it claims there is an error with the link being [my website url]/0

Comment: Can you check if your request is getting fired and what response your getting in the debugger?